# Putting Date from Parse.com to same type as System Date

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-date, android-dateutils

I want to ask, how can I put Date from Parse.com (which is in format "Sat Mar 01 15:52:20 GMT+1:00 2014") to same Date type as the date and time in system. Second thing I want to ask is, how to get only for example "month:day:hour:minute:year" from Parse.com even though the Date is given in format as written above.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just try like this you can achieve the Date format conversion easily...

```
    String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    String outputPattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy   hh:mm a";
    SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

    Date date1 = null;

    if (date != null) {
        try {
            date1 = inFormat.parse(date);
            str = outputFormat.format(date1);
            Log.d(null, str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        str = " ";
    }
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot ! One more question: can I use the if/else method with dates? For example if(str>currentDate) -> do something. (If some date is higher than current date..)

Comment: You can compare like as Strings if the String is Equal means you can proceed your logic inside the IF statements..And try this link http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ ...

Comment: if (removeTime(questionDate).equals(removeTime(today)) 
  ...

public Date removeTime(Date date) {    
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    cal.setTime(date);  
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);  
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);  
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  
    return cal.getTime(); 
}

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse(  // Parse input string as a `OffsetDateTime` object, with the given offset-from-UTC.
    "Sat Mar 01 15:52:20 GMT+1:00 2014" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O uuuu" , Locale.US )    
).toInstant()          // Convert from the given offset-from-UTC to UTC.
```

## Details

You may be confused about how date and time tracking work in Java. The java.util.Date class tracks the number of milliseconds since the [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29). It has no String inside.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

If you are receiving a string such as `"Sat Mar 01 15:52:20 GMT+1:00 2014"`, parse as a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). By the way, this is a *terrible* format. Better to exchange date-time values as text using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, whenever possible.

Specify a formatting pattern to match your input.

Note the `Locale` argument. [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

```
String input = "Sat Mar 01 15:52:20 GMT+1:00 2014" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O uuuu" , Locale.US );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f  );
```

Generate a String to represent the value of this `OffsetDateTime` object in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

> odt.toString(): 2014-03-01T15:52:20+01:00

To generate strings in other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter`.

To view that same moment through the wall-clock time of UTC, extract a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;  // Extract an `Instant`, always in UTC.
```

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** This section is now outmoded, but retained as history. FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is the go-to library for data-time handling. The java.util.Date & .Calendar & SimpleTextFormat classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome (not Sun’s best work). Those old classes have been supplanted in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) by the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) which is inspired by Joda-Time.

In Joda-Time, a DateTime object is similar to a java.util.Date object in that it tracks number of milliseconds-since-Unix-epoch. But different in that a DateTime does know its own assigned time zone.

Here's a bit of code to get you started. Search StackOverflow to find more examples.

One problem with that string you gave as example. The offset-from-GMT is `+1:00` without a leading zero before the `1`. That cannot be parsed directly by Joda-Time. Hopefully that was a typo made by you and not a lousy format being generated by Parse.com.

The formats you see below are the standard, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```
String input = "Sat Mar 01 15:52:20 GMT+01:00 2014";

DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy" ).withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" );
DateTime dateTimeLosAngeles = formatterInput.withZone( timeZone ).parseDateTime( input );

DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeLosAngeles.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "SS" );
String output = formatterOutput.print( dateTimeLosAngeles );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeLosAngeles: " + dateTimeLosAngeles );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
input: Sat Mar 01 15:52:20 GMT+01:00 2014
dateTimeLosAngeles: 2014-03-01T06:52:20.000-08:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-03-01T14:52:20.000Z
output: 3/1/14 6:52 AM
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped and I hope, it will help the others too